# As3: pass class as parameter and call static method dynmically

Tags: actionscript-3

Lets say i have a class **cMenu**, wich has a function **displayMenu()**. This function calls the static function **init()** in a submenu class, depending on what is passed to displayMenu(), like this:

```
cMenu.displayMenu('cMenuMain');

public class cMenu
{   
    public static function displayMenu(sMenu:String):void{

        switch(sMenu) {
            case 'cMenuMain':
                cMenuMain.init();
                break;
            case 'cMenuHighscore':
                cMenuHighscore.init();
                break;
        }

    }
}

public class cMenuMain
{   
    public static function init():void{
        trace('cMenuMain');
    }
}
```

**My question:** Can i somehow avoid the switch and call the function init() of the submenu dynamically accroding to what sMenu is set to?
Something like `eval(sMenu+'.init()');`

Thanks for hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your submenus class always implement an init method (you can use an interface to ensure that), you can pass the targeted submenu class as parameter to the displayMenu method

```
public static function displayMenu(submenuClass:*):void{
 // if you need to perform something here depending on the submenu class
 if (submenuClass is cMenuMain) {
  // do something
 } 
 submenuClass.init()
}

displayMenu(cMenuMain);
```

Comment: Doesn't that mean you will have to have a big if/else statement for all the different classes anyway?

Answer (score 1):

To get a class by a name string you can use `getDefinitionByName`, like the example below:

```
var ClassReference:Class = getDefinitionByName(sMenu) as Class;
```

But then you will not know exactly what type your `ClassReference` is, so will not know if it even has an `init` method.

If you did know the type you could just call a static method:

```
ClassReference.init();
```

Comment: When I call `ClassReference.init();` I got the error **ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable cMenuMain is not defined.**. But cMenuMain.init(); works, so cMenuMain must be there.